# Possible armadillo mat bug when saving a mat in an external array?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, mat, armadillo

I have a problem which is like this. I want to create an armadillo matrix backed by an array, which is fine and easy to do. However when I try to save the resulting mat in an array of armadillo mats' changes to the underlying c array no longer changes the mat. Example code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main() {
    Mat<float>* test = (Mat<float>*)malloc(sizeof(Mat<float>));
    float *Amem = (float*) malloc(4*sizeof(float));
    Amem[0] = 0; Amem[1] = 1; Amem[2] = 2; Amem[3] = 3;
    Mat<float> A = Mat<float>(Amem, 2, 2, false, false);
    test[0] = A;

    test[0].print();
    Amem[1] = 100;
    test[0].print();
    A.print();
    free(test);
    free(Amem);
    return 0;
}
```

When the following code is run, it results in:

```
test[0] = 0  2
          1  3

test[0] = 0  2
          1  3

A = 0  2
    100 3
```

Why isn't A and test[0] the same? Is there anyway to make them the same?

Comment: Why would you suspect that the bug is in a library, which is used by many people, rather than your code? Why are you using `malloc` in C++ (instead of `new`)? Since it doesn't call constructors, your code exhibits UB.

Comment: `test[0] = A` does a matrix copy. This is standard C++ behavior.

Comment: I suspected the bug was in my code, I just could not see what I did wrong, sorry if the question was badly formulated.

Ahh, yeah you are right, I feel like an idiot. So is there a way to do what I want to do, which is save the armadillo mat in an array?

Comment: @Xaja - use the [`field` class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) to store an array of matrix objects

Comment: Thanks, the field class should solve my problem. But i've run into another curiosity about this.

Even if I dont make the middle step of creating A then test[0] = A, IE I create test[0] = Mat<float>(Amem, 2, 2, false, false) i still get the same behaviour of test[0] matrix not changing? shouldnt that behave just like A?